# Is there any way to know when chip is removed in primeng multiselect?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using this one https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect with chips
My field is connected to a reactive form field and when I select and deselect items from the select with the checkbox it works, however when I remove chips when dropdown is closed the change is not reflected to the dynamic form. I was wondering is there any event that tracks when the chips are removed with the X on them, so I can patch the updated value to the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [a bug](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9579), here is [`removeChip()` function](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/multiselect/multiselect.ts#L667):

```
removeChip(chip: any) {
    this.value = this.value.filter(val => !ObjectUtils.equals(val, chip, this.dataKey));
    this.updateFilledState();
}
```

where `onModelChange()` is not called with new value.

As a workaround (before PrimeNG team will fix it) you can call it manually.
First get reference to your multi select:

```
@ViewChild(MultiSelect) ms: MultiSelect;
```

and then extend `removeChip()` function within `ngAfterViewInit` hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const originalRemoveChip = this.ms.removeChip;
  this.ms.removeChip = (...args) => {
    originalRemoveChip.apply(this.ms, args);
    this.ms.onModelChange(this.ms.value);
  };
}
```

Here is working [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-ag9pfc)

Comment: thank you, I love this trick !